# How to Check SSO Session from the first time without click on Sign In button

Tags: single-sign-on

I'm researching on SSO but there is one thing I coudn't understand is how SSO consumer can get session without clicking on Login Button. I can explain the case as below:

I have:

1. accounts.domain.com (Identity Server. Already Allow consumer 1 & 2)
2. myapp.com (Consumer 1)
3. yourapp.com (Consumer 2)

When I go to `myapp.com` -> I have no permisson or no session to access the server resources.

I click on `Sign In` button in `myapp.com`, this will redirect to `accounts.domain.com` and after authenticated, I get back to `myapp.com` with my local session.

The question is: When I go to `yourapp.com`, I already have session without click on `Sign In` button.

The real case is `google.com`, `accounts.google.com`, `youtube.com`, ...

I don't know how it works and how to implement this?

And one more question, Can I use `Auth0` or `Google Cloud Identity` or `AWS Cognito` to build my `Identity Provider` like google did?

Can someone support me in this?

Answer (score 0):

To better understand the concept u should 1st know what happens when u use SSO login.

I will take google and YouTube as examples.

When u login to google using your credentials u will not only get a **local session but a single sign on token**. We generally have this as SAML which is **security assertion markup language** token.

This SAML token will be stored in your client or browser in this case. 
Now when u try to load youtube in the same browser this token will be sent to the IDP along with the request. Since the **IDP knows that this user is already authenticated** it will check for authorization for the particular website in this case YouTube, the page loads.

Comment: Thanks @gkrthk, It means, I will have `SAML` token and it could be store in `Cookies` or `Local Storage`, Ex: `google.com` stored this `SAML` token in `Cookies` then How `Youtube` can get that token to check `authenticated` use?

Comment: It&#39;s basically cookies in google&#39;s case and they will be added for all domains under google once you login, like accounts.google.com accounts.youtube.com etc